# creating a custom table in stata

Tags: stata

How can I create a table that shows mean and SD for 2 categories: "Old" versus "Updated" across 2020 2021 and 2022? There are 10 variables that need to be summarized?

See picture for hint.

I have tried stuff like `asdoc` and other commands interacted with `bysort` but each says "too many variables (to sort by) specified)

Comment: There is no picture that I can see. You need to show code you tried, not just allude to it. Does "across 2020 2021 and 2022" mean for those years combined, or separately? See the `stata` tag wiki for detailed advice on presenting reproducible examples.  You don't need to show 10 variables, as 2 would be enough to show what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very basic way of doing that.

```
sysuse auto

tabstat price mpg rep78 headroom trunk weight length, ///
    by(foreign) nototal statistics(mean sd)
```

Comment: I am afraid you misinterpreted the question but thanks

Comment: So what was missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you would export `tabstat` to a csv file:

```
ssc install estout

sysuse auto

estpost tabstat price mpg weight length if inlist(rep78,3,4,5), by(foreign) ///
statistics(mean sd) columns(statistics) listwise nototal

esttab . using stats.csv, main(mean) aux(sd) ///
replace unstack  plain noobs nomtitle 

shell open stats.csv
```